# File manipulation in C - deleting a specific line from a file in C

Tags: c

My goal is to delete a specific line from a file given a number. This code deletes a file, but it also deletes the first character in line 1.

My file has:

```
Mary had a little lamb
Twinkle twinkle little stars
Baa baa black sheep
```

when I delete line 2, the file would be modified like this:

```
ary had a little lamb
Baa baa black sheep
```

Also, if I delete the line 1, the line will be deleted but the line 1 will be blank. It would be modified like this:

```
1.
2. Baa baa black sheep
```

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #define filename "file.txt"
    int main()
    {
     FILE *fp1, *fp2;
        char c;
        int del_line, temp = 1;
        fp1 = fopen(filename, "r");
        c = getc(fp1);
        while (c != EOF)
        {
            printf("%c", c);
            c = getc(fp1);
        }
    
        rewind(fp1);
        printf(" \n Enter line number of the line to be deleted:");
        scanf("%d", &del_line);
    
        fp2 = fopen("copy.c", "w");
        c = getc(fp1);
        while (c != EOF) {
            c = getc(fp1);
            if (c == '\n')
            temp++;
            if (temp != del_line)
            {
            putc(c, fp2);
            }
        }
        fclose(fp1);
        fclose(fp2);
        remove(filename);
        rename("copy.c", filename);
        printf("\n The contents of file after being modified are as  follows:\n");
        fp1 = fopen(filename, "r");
        c = getc(fp1);
        while (c != EOF) {
            printf("%c", c);
            c = getc(fp1);
        }
        fclose(fp1);
        return 0;
    }
```

Edited (but my last problem is not yet solved):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define filename "file.txt"
int main()
{
 FILE *fp1, *fp2;
    char c;
    int del_line, temp = 1;
    fp1 = fopen(filename, "r");
    c = getc(fp1);
    while (c != EOF)
    {
        printf("%c", c);
        c = getc(fp1);
    }

    rewind(fp1);
    printf(" \n Enter line number of the line to be deleted:");
    scanf("%d", &del_line);

    fp2 = fopen("copy.c", "w");

    while( (c = getc(fp1)) != EOF ){
        if (c == '\n')
        temp++;
        if (temp != del_line)
        {
        putc(c, fp2);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    remove(filename);
    rename("copy.c", filename);
    printf("\n The contents of file after being modified are as  follows:\n");
    fp1 = fopen(filename, "r");
    c = getc(fp1);
    while (c != EOF) {
        printf("%c", c);
        c = getc(fp1);
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use the standard idiom `while( (c=getc(fp1)) != EOF )` and your error (calling getc() one too many times) will magically disappear.

Answer (score 2):

The error is in the lines:

```
fp2 = fopen("copy.c", "w");
c = getc(fp1);
while (c != EOF) {
    c = getc(fp1);
```

The first `getc` reads the first character in the file.  The next `getc` reads the 2nd character, and the first character is discarded.  Use the standard idiom to avoid this mistake:

```
int c;  /* Must not be char !! */
while( (c = getc(fp1)) != EOF ){ ...
```

Comment: Always amazed at how uncommon the common standard idiom is... `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin did you see my last problem? I'm trying ways to solve it, but i do not really know where I went wrong

Comment: @starter other than not validating the opens and initial reads, nothing jumps out. Give me a sec and I'll check it further. --- (works fine here, what is not working for you?)

Comment: i think it looks fine in console but when I check in the file.txt it will go from this

'1. Mary had a little lamb
2. Twinkle twinkle little stars
3. Baa baa black sheep'

to this:
'1. 
2. Twinkle twinkle little stars
3. Baa baa black sheep'

Comment: I see the issue -- hold on another sec. The problem is your logic with `if (c == '\n') temp++`. When you delete the first line, you reach `'\n'` and increment `temp++`. It is no longer equal to `1` so the `'\n'` is printed as the first character in the file... If you turn your logic around and use a second loop, e.g.  `if (temp == del_line) while ((c = getc(fp1)) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}`.

Comment: wait i'm trying to understand

Comment: Just reverse the order; check `c == '\n'` *after* you check `temp != del_line`.

Comment: To avoid an infinite loop (when `char` is _unsigned_) with `while (c != EOF)`, use `int c;`.

Answer (score 0):

The first line copied to the output is missing the first character because the initial c = getc(fp1) outside of the loop read (and consumed) the first character of the first line of the file.  Perhaps you could remove it, and change the loop test to feof(fp1).